# After editing opened file, how to save the changes?

Tags: java, swing, file, io, jtextfield

I am able to open file through the code below on text field `txt1`.  How can I save the changes automatically after editing in `txt1` field in this same function by using Buffered Reader or anything else?

```
 private void btnOpenfileActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt)                                            
{ 
 String file="";
  JFileChooser chooser = new JFileChooser("./");
    int i = chooser.showOpenDialog(null);
    if (i == 0) {
        File f = chooser.getSelectedFile();
        filelocation=f.getAbsolutePath();
    System.out.println(f); 

        try {
            FileReader fr = new FileReader(f); //file location passed
            BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(fr);
            String temp = "";

                while ((temp = br.readLine()) != null) 
               {

               file += temp+"\n";

               }
            txt1.setText(file); //txt1 is a text field in split pane

            fr.close();
          } 
            catch (Exception e) 
           {
            System.out.println(e);
           }

}
```

Comment: is it not getting saved on its own?have you checked?

Comment: does this even compile? What is `file += temp+"\n";` doing?

Comment: Obiviously, what is 'file' here. at line file +=temp+"\n";

Comment: 1) For better help sooner, post an [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) (Minimal, Complete, Verifiable Example). 2) For loading and saving text in/from a `JTextComponent`, see [`read(Reader,Object)`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/javax/swing/text/JTextComponent.html#read-java.io.Reader-java.lang.Object-) & [`write(Writer)`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/javax/swing/text/JTextComponent.html#write-java.io.Writer-).

Comment: It is a String type declared in a method.

Comment: Tip: Be sure to add @NikhilTalreja (or whoever, the `@` is important) to *notify* a person of a new comment.  Exactly one person can be notified per comment.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For loading and saving text in/from a `JTextComponent`, see [`read(Reader,Object)`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/javax/swing/text/JTextComponent.html#read-java.io.Reader-java.lang.Object-) & [`write(Writer)`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/javax/swing/text/JTextComponent.html#write-java.io.Writer-).

For detecting changes to a `JTextField` [add an action listener](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/javax/swing/JTextField.html#addActionListener-java.awt.event.ActionListener-) (that will typically fire when the user presses the enter key), or [a `DocumentListener`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/javax/swing/event/DocumentListener.html).

Answer (score 2):

You need a Writer and a save button or something else to trigger the save operation:

```
    final BufferedWriter bufferedWriter = new BufferedWriter(new FileWriter(myFile));
    try
    {
        bufferedWriter.write(text);
    }
    catch (final IOException exception)
    {
        // Error handling.
    }
    finally
    {
        bufferedWriter.close();
    }
```

Comment: *"and a save button"*  Not necessarily.  We can [add an action listener](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/javax/swing/JTextField.html#addActionListener-java.awt.event.ActionListener-) that will typically fire when the user presses the enter key, or [a `DocumentListener`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/javax/swing/event/DocumentListener.html).